# Write a foreach loop for array of SimpleXMLElements

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, simplexml

I am using the XPath in PHP 5 to parse a XML document. The problem I have is writing a `foreach` to correctly display the following array:

XML document sample

> value 1
>           value 2

```
           $xmlfile = 'link_to_file.xml';                       
            $xmlRaw = file_get_contents($xmlfile);      
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlRaw);
            $install_files = $xml->xpath('//files');
            foreach($install_files as $row)
            {
              echo $row['file'];
            }
```

//var_dump for $row gives the following

> ```
>                array(1) {
>                   [0]=>
>                   object(SimpleXMLElement)#21 (2) {
>                     ["file"]=>
>                     string(12) "value 1"
>                     ["folder"]=>
>                     string(8) "value 2"
>                   }
>                 }
> ```

Ideally I would like to get the value by using `$row['file']` or `$row['folder']`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @mjames, is this homework related?

Comment: It is actually for a script I am creating.

Comment: cool... just checking, the title seemed a little "homework-ish".

Comment: I actually had a different title but it was changed by the moderators :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in your array are *SimpleXMLElement* objects. You can access their [properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) with the `$object->property` syntax. So try this:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    echo $row->folder . $row->file;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize i had to use it in an object form ->file instead of ['file]. Works great now :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your example correctly,

```
foreach ($array as $row)
{
    // do something with $row['file'] or $row['folder']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process only one element you don't necessarily need a loop, but it doesn't hurt either.
According to your output `file` and `folder` are child-elements of the element returned for your xpath query. You can access them via `$parentElement->childElement`. If they were attributes you'd use `$element['attributeName']`

```
$foo = new SimpleXMLElement(getData());

foreach( $foo->xpath('row[@id="r2"]') as $row ) {
  echo $row->file, " | ", $row->folder, "\n";
}
echo "-----\n";

// same thing if you have more than one element in your result set
foreach( $foo->xpath('row[@id="r2" or @id="r3"]') as $row ) {
  echo $row->file, " | ", $row->folder, "\n";
}

function getData() {
  return '<foo>
    <row id="r1">
      <file>value 1.1</file>
      <folder>value 1.2</folder>
    </row>
    <row id="r2">
      <file>value 2.1</file>
      <folder>value 2.2</folder>
    </row>
    <row id="r3">
      <file>value 3.1</file>
      <folder>value 3.2</folder>
    </row>
  </foo>';
}
```

prints

```
value 2.1 | value 2.2
-----
value 2.1 | value 2.2
value 3.1 | value 3.2
```